# Devise routes on Ruby on Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have just installed Devise and now I want to make better style for Devise. I have added in application.html.rb link to edit Devise user profile, but when I visit this page and then go back for example to index page I have no routes matches error.

HTML generates this link for home/index: http://localhost:3000/assets?controller=devise%2Fhome

but really need to be: http://localhost:3000/home/index

There goes something wrong after visiting Devise user pages.

**My navigation:**

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <h2>Izvēlne</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu"><%= link_to "Jaunumi" ,:controller=>"home", :action => "index" %></a></li>
      <li><a class="menu"><%= link_to "Par skolu" ,:controller=>"home", :action => "par_skolu" %></a></li>
      <li><a class="menu"><%= link_to "Galerijas" ,:controller=>"home", :action => "galerijas" %></a></li>
      <li><a class="menu"><%= link_to "Skolotāji" ,:controller=>"home", :action => "personals" %></a></li>
      <li><a class="menu"><%= link_to "Kontaktinformācija" ,:controller=>"home", :action => "kontakti" %></a></li>
      <li><a class="menu"><%= link_to "Personāla pieeja" ,:controller=>"home", :action => "pers_pieeja" %></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  <h2>Administrācija</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "Lietotāju rediģēšana", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Rakstu rediģēšana" ,:controller=>"posts", :action => "index" %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Galeriju rediģēšana" ,:controller=>"admin", :action => "galeriju_red" %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
devise_for :users

get "admin/galeriju_red"

resources :posts

get "admin/rakstu_red"

get "home/par_skolu"

get "home/personals"

get "home/kontakti"

get "home/pers_pieeja"

get "home/galerijas"

get "home/index"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only idea I can think of is changing your routes from:

```
get "home/index"
```

to

```
match "/home/index" => "home#index", :via => [:get]
```

They are equivalent, but **match** makes path helpers available, so your links in menu view could be like this:

```
<%= link_to "Home" main_app.home_index_path %>
```

Main_app is a built-in Rails helper and it gives access to Rails routes inside Engine.

If you matched simply /home, path helper would be called home_path.

I hope this fixes your problem.

Reference: [Routing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls)

Comment: I have changed all my navigation links in application to paths, not this style :controller=>"home", :action => "index" and now all is working!